# Static properties on a trait cannot be overriden by the class that uses the trait

Tags: php

The error seems off, given that my static property is the same both on my trait and my class.

```php
trait Sluggable
{
  protected static $column = 'slug'; 
}

class Product
{
  use Sluggable;

  protected static $column = 'code';
}
```

> PHP Fatal error:  Product and Sluggable define the same property ($column) in the composition of Product. However, the definition differs and is considered incompatible. Class was composed.

I tried (and failed) with both of these scenarios:

- Using `public` modifier instead
- On PHP 7.2 and 8.0
- With or without property type hint

I cannot use a regular class (because my target class "Product" actually extends another class in the reality).

Anybodu has a clue?

Comment: Looking at [PHP's example](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php#language.oop5.interfaces.examples.ex4) of the same error, the initial value must be the same too: `If a trait defines a property then a class can not define a property with the same name unless it is compatible (same visibility AND INITIAL VALUE), otherwise a fatal error is issued.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php):

> If a trait defines a property then a class can not define a property
> with the same name unless it is compatible (same visibility and
> **initial value**), otherwise a fatal error is issued.

A simple solution is to override the value inside the constructor of the class, but in your case there is a static property so you cannot do this.

You have to change approach and use methods that have more flexibility and you can declare them as abstract inside the traits.

```
trait AbstractSluggable {
    abstract protected static function getColumn();
}

class Product
{
  use AbstractSluggable;

  protected static function getColumn() {
      return 'code';
  }
  
  public static function demo() {
      return self::getColumn();
  }
  
}

echo Product::demo();
```

Or if for some reasons you have to put your Sluggable trait as is, you can create another trait and tell the class to use it with the `insteadof`

```
trait Sluggable
{
  protected static function getColumn() {
      return 'slug';
  }
}

trait AbstractSluggable {
    abstract protected static function getColumn();
}

class Product
{
  use Sluggable,AbstractSluggable {
      AbstractSluggable::getColumn insteadof Sluggable;
  }
  protected static function getColumn() {
      return 'code';
  }
  
  public static function demo() {
      return self::getColumn();
  }
  
}

echo Product::demo();
```

Comment: Yes indeed this is what I ended up with. The error bugged me a bit to be honest since I have the same "defintion", a default value as well (it's just not the same). I don't get the point in overriding the same property with the same... value. I'll go for what you've proposed for now thank you!